# Shaperenderer crash libgdx

Tags: java, android, crash, libgdx, draw

I'm developing a new application with libgdx and in my source code i'm using the shaperenderer class but since I've bought my new tablet (Acer Iconia One 10 B3-A20), my application always crash without displaying any errors after calling the "shaperenderer.end()" method . Even when I create a simple class as the following one, have I missing something?

```
public class Test implements Screen {
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.rect(30,30,200,200);
        shapeRenderer.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        shapeRenderer.dispose();

    }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT:

After placing some breakpoints into the "shaperenderer.end()"method i have noticed that the program crash after calling the "mesh.render()" method, and particularly when it call the "bind" method of the Mesh class (for binding the shaders).

Is it normal?

Comment: What does Logcat show?

Comment: 02-09 17:38:39.825 17727-17759 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xffffff87e63000 in tid 17759 (GLThread 5934)

And as i said i don't load any images :/

EDIT: No i don't make multithreading and i have only a class "Application manager" that extends Game, i create the "Test" object on the "create "methods , that's it

Comment: Have you made any changes from the default Libgdx Android launcher class? Are you doing any multithreading?

Comment: i have edited my last comment =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a camera first on your show method:

```
OrthographicCamera camera;
[...]
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false);
```

and on render method set the projectionMatrix before draw:

```
    camera.update();
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```